# subversion logs - 24 hour time frame

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

Im trying to put together a nightly build and would like subversion to export .sql files from our repo dynamically based on everything committed to the branch in the last 24 hours.

Is this possible? I know I can get the logs to check between date ranges, but I want that range to move on 24 hours each time. I'm using bash as a build script.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read SVN Book, ["Revision Specifiers"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html) chapter, and "Is Subversion a Day Early?" section most carefully
2. Read [man date](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html) page

After 1+2 you will be able to get needed datetimes for using in `svn log -r {$FROM}:{$TO}` (and check and skip first log, if it will be out of range)